# predict function is returning exponential values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have built and trained a sequential binary classification model using keras layers. Everything seems to work fine. Until I start using the predict method. This function starts to give me a weird exponential value rather than a probability.
[This what I get after training and using predict method on the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdpar.png)

This classification model has two classes lets say a cat or a dog, so I was expecting the result to be something like [99.9999, 0.0001] suggesting that its a cat. I'm not sure how to interpret the value that I'm getting back instead.

Here is the code I have:

```
# Get the data.
    (train_texts, train_labels), (val_texts, val_labels) = data
    train_labels = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32')
    val_labels = np.asarray(val_labels).astype('float32')

    # Vectorizing data
    train_texts,val_texts, word_index = vectorize_data.sequence_vectorize(
        train_texts, val_texts)

    # Building the model architecture( adding layers to the model)
    model = build_model.simple_model_layers(train_texts.shape[1:])

    # Setting and compiling with the features like the optimizer, loss and metrics functions
    model = build_model.simple_model_compile(model=model)

    # This is when the learning happens
    history = model.fit(train_texts,
                        train_labels,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        validation_data=(val_texts, val_labels),
                        verbose=VERBOSE_OFF, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    print('Validation accuracy: {acc}, loss: {loss}'.format(
        acc=history['val_acc'][-1], loss=history['val_loss'][-1]))

    # loading data to predict on
    test_text = any
    with open('text_req.pickle', 'rb') as pickle_file:
        test_text = pickle.load(pickle_file)


    print('Lets make a prediction of this requirement:')
    prediction = model.predict(test_text, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
    print(prediction)
```

Comment: That weird value is considered by the neural network to be 0. It's not an exponential but 2.977094 * 10^{-12}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: That output is just a number in scientific notation.

Comment: Actually getting that number was not really a problem. My problem is I don't really know what to make of it. I added some more information to the post:
"This classification model has two classes lets say a cat or a dog, so I was expecting the result to be something like [99.9999, 0.0001] suggesting that its a cat. I'm not sure how to interpret the value that I'm getting back instead."

Comment: If you use a sigmoid as the last layer, it's normal to have only one value. It corresponds to the probability that the class is 1

Answer (score -1):

Usually unskewed data are converted to its log values while training.
So

```
np.exp(your_value)
```

might be something you are looking for.

Comment: doing this just returns 1 for me. I was actually expecting the predict(data) to return two values which are the probabilities of classes it's classifying the data into.